# Angular Material: Show checkbox when mouse over table row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular Material table with checkbox on first column. I only want to show the checkbox when the mouse is over the table row.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/pabvkrmvbab?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.css

I can use css to change the row color on hover, but not sure how to use similar solution to show the checkbox

```
.mat-row:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can do it as follows.**

**Add new `boolean` property called `show` to `ELEMENT_DATA`.**

```
  addShowCheckboxProperty() {
    ELEMENT_DATA.map((data: any) => {
      data.show = false
    });
  }
```

**Use `opacity` property on `mat-checkbox` to show/hide checkboxes as follows.**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <mat-checkbox [style.opacity]="row.show || selection.isSelected(row) ? 100 : 0"
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
  </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

**Handle `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events on `tr` as follows.**

**HTML**

```
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)" 
      (mouseover)="handleMouseOver(row)" 
      (mouseleave)="handleMouseLeave(row)">
  </tr>
```

**TS**

```
  handleMouseOver(row) {
    const position = row.position;
    ELEMENT_DATA.map((data: any) => {
      if (data.position === position) {
        data.show = true;
      }
    });
  }

  handleMouseLeave(row) {
    const position = row.position;
    ELEMENT_DATA.map((data: any) => {
      if (data.position === position) {
        data.show = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

**As you show your `checkbox` on `mouseover` I think no need of select all `checkbox` on table header row.**
**Find Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmmeqr?file=app/table-selection-example.ts).**

Comment: This is a good solution, but should be changed as follows. Set the opacity of the checkbox to zero rather than `*ngIf`ing the checkbox component, and include the row selection status as part of the condition so that selected rows always show the checkbox `<mat-checkbox [style.opacity]="row.show || selection.isSelected(row) ? 100 : 0" ...>`. Set show just true in the mouseover for the row (and not false for all other rows) - set show to false in a mouseleave handler - this hides the checkbox when the mouse leaves the whole table.

Comment: @G. Tranter  Thanks for your suggestion.  It is a very good one and I updated my answer as your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Easily done with CSS.

```
.mat-row:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.mat-row mat-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.mat-row:hover mat-checkbox {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has helped with something i'm looking at Any ideas on how we adapt this to also keep the checkboxes visible if they have been checked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngIf` to check a variable and with `mouseenter` you can set the same variable to `true`, to be able to hide just set the same variable to `false` with `mouseleave`.

A things like that:

#### HTML

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" (mouseenter)="isHover=true" 
(mouseleave)="isHover=false">

  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="isHover" (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="isHover" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

... 

</table>
```

#### Componet

```js
isHover: boolean = false;
```

In this case the checkboxes are popping, but you can add css with transition to have a smooth effect or whetever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a slightly different take on 
[Sudarshana Dayananda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855019/7824944) so you don't have to add new fields to your data:

1) Ensure that your data object (for each row) has an "id" field.

2) Add the following to the mat-row:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="onRowClicked(row)"
            (mouseover)='mouseOverRow(row)' (mouseleave)='mouseLeaveRow(row)'></tr>
```

3) And then in .ts  set the currently hovered row as a class variable:

```
mouseOverRow(row) {
this.hoveredRow = row;}

mouseLeaveRow(row) {
this.hoveredRow = null;}
```

4) So on the checkbox/button you can add:

```
[class.buttonInvisible]='!hoveredRow || (element.id !== hoveredRow.id)'
```

My component looks like this:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                    <!-- {{ 'Generic.select' | translate }} -->
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style='text-align:end; width:40px;'>
                    <button [class.buttonInvisible]='!hoveredRow || (element.id !== hoveredRow.id)' class='tableActionButton' mat-icon-button
                        color="accent" aria-label="Delete" (click)="onDeleteClicked(element);$event.stopPropagation();">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
```

where buttonInvisible css:

```
.buttonInvisible{
opacity: 0 !important;}
```

Let me quickly explain the logic here. The buttonInvisible class is conditionally applied to all checkboxes/buttons when (1) the class hoverRow is not initialised (so no hovering has happened yet) or (2) the row element id does not match the current hovered row's id. So you'll only see the checkbox over the specific row if the id matches the currently hovered set row.